# How to get `FindCurvePath` to return only one list

Tags: interpolation, cluster-analysis

As you can see below, `FindCurvePath` returns only a part of the list, resulting in a partial interpolation. I would like to interpolate *all* the points.

[image]

Complete code:

```
pts = {{1.93423, 0.641189}, {1.9358, 0.630954}, {1.9371, 
    0.650986}, {1.93919, 0.621439}, {1.94365, 0.61225}, {1.94597, 
    0.655907}, {1.94882, 0.603438}, {1.95455, 0.594968}, {1.95606, 
    0.656171}, {1.96069, 0.586872}, {1.96595, 0.654537}, {1.96714, 
    0.579184}, {1.97424, 0.571486}, {1.97578, 0.651937}, {1.98145, 
    0.564318}, {1.98531, 0.648845}, {1.98881, 0.557548}, {1.9948, 
    0.645393}, {1.99647, 0.551004}, {2.00419, 0.641735}, {2.00463, 
    0.544488}, {2.01275, 0.538373}, {2.01363, 0.637894}, {2.02088, 
    0.532551}, {2.02306, 0.633956}, {2.02915, 0.526872}, {2.0323, 
    0.630046}, {2.03751, 0.521304}, {2.04156, 0.62611}, {2.04595, 
    0.515815}, {2.05077, 0.622207}, {2.0544, 0.510398}, {2.05999, 
    0.618333}, {2.06294, 0.504962}, {2.06934, 0.614459}, {2.07145, 
    0.499549}, {2.07862, 0.610677}, {2.07994, 0.494119}, {2.08831, 
    0.606811}, {2.0884, 0.488658}, {2.09683, 0.483151}, {2.09804, 
    0.603014}, {2.1052, 0.477593}, {2.10739, 0.599448}, {2.11352, 
    0.471977}, {2.11717, 0.59581}, {2.12178, 0.466298}, {2.12666, 
    0.592359}, {2.12999, 0.460556}, {2.13608, 0.589006}, {2.13813, 
    0.454749}, {2.14553, 0.585711}, {2.14629, 0.448827}, {2.15441, 
    0.44282}, {2.155, 0.582465}, {2.16246, 0.436763}, {2.1645, 
    0.579252}, {2.174, 0.576075}, {2.1835, 0.572919}, {2.19313, 
    0.569731}, {2.2027, 0.56656}, {2.21246, 0.563307}, {2.2221, 
    0.560059}, {2.23174, 0.556768}, {2.24124, 0.553468}, {2.2507, 
    0.550113}, {2.26013, 0.546683}, {2.26966, 0.543124}, {2.27906, 
    0.539506}, {2.28836, 0.535809}, {2.29765, 0.531988}, {2.30703, 
    0.527995}, {2.31622, 0.523934}, {2.32532, 0.519765}, {2.33437, 
    0.515457}, {2.34337, 0.511008}, {2.35234, 0.506407}, {2.36121, 
    0.501682}, {2.36999, 0.496834}};
path = (FindCurvePath@pts)[[1]];
curve = Interpolation[#, Method -> "Spline"] &@
   MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #1} &, pts[[path]]];
Show[ParametricPlot[curve[t], {t, 1, Length[path]}, 
  AspectRatio -> 3/4, PlotStyle -> Red], ListPlot[pts]]
```

If I replace `[[1]]` by `[[2]]` in `path=`, I get the second part:

[image]

How to get both curves at once?

---

**Edit** 
I found an example which could not be treated with Michael's solution. It appears sorting the points from one end of the curve to the other end makes it more robust. Unfortunately, I don't know how to detect the position of one end so this is not fully automatic.

This is the complete code (mostly that of Michael's answer):

```
(* to put an edge point in the first position *)
pts = 
 Sort[pts, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &]; (* replace [[1]] with [[2]] if the curve is cut horizontally *)
ptstmp = Drop[pts, {1}];
ptsOrdered = {pts[[1]]};
For[i = 1, i < Length[pts], i++,
  AppendTo[ptsOrdered, First@Nearest[ptstmp, pts[[i]]]];
  ptstmp = 
   Drop[ptstmp, Position[ptstmp, Nearest[ptstmp, pts[[i]]]]]];
ListPlot[ptsOrdered]

segments = FindCurvePath@ptsOrdered;
edges = Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ segments;
edges = Join @@ edges;
g = Graph@edges;
path = FindShortestPath[g, ##] & @@ 
   Flatten[Position[VertexDegree[g], 1]];
curve = Interpolation[#, Method -> "Spline"] &@
   MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #1} &, ptsOrdered[[path]]];
Show[ParametricPlot[curve[t], {t, 1, Length[path]}, 
  AspectRatio -> 3/4, PlotStyle -> Red], ListPlot[ptsOrdered]]
```

Output (the data is not included in the question):
[image]

Comment: As  of Mathematica v9, you can't. But you may build your own function. See here for a similar (but not exact) example http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75867/193

Comment: @belisarius Is there a fundamental reason why `FindCurvePath` stops somewhere rather than somewhere else?

Comment: @anderstood Is it possible that you provide the second data-set too? You can copy it to [hastebin.com](http://hastebin.com/) and give the link here.

Comment: @halirutan Sure, there it is: http://hastebin.com/etakobosuq.mel. The procedure works for the first list of points (`ptsWorks`) while it fails for the second (`ptsDoesnt`). Yet, the two lists are very similar (they were generated from the same long list).

Answer (score 7):

`FindCurvePath` splits the `pts` into two pieces, but the segments have a common point:

```
segments = FindCurvePath@ pts;
segments[[All, 1]]
(*  {2, 2}  *)
```

Assuming that this always happens, namely that all the points are split into segments that share endpoints when *in the mind of the user* the points constitute a single smooth curve, one can join the lists, reversing a list when necessary.  Of course, the assumption should be verified first.  Further, `FindCurvePath` sometimes drops points and does other things automatically.  The path returned may depend on the order of the points.  Apparently `FindCurvePath` does not do a full global analysis, but proceeds locally or semi-locally.  Thus writing code such as in belisarius's answer to [Finding a function that fits the shape of an image](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75855/finding-a-function-that-fits-the-shape-of-an-image/75867#75867) is probably the most robust approach.

Taking a big-hammer approach, here is way that works in the OP's not-too-troublesome case.

```
segments = FindCurvePath@ pts;
edges = Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ segments;
edges = Join @@ edges;
path = FindHamiltonianPath@ Graph@ edges;
curve = Interpolation[#, Method -> "Spline"] &@
   MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #1} &, pts[[path]]];
Show[ParametricPlot[curve[t], {t, 1, Length[path]}, 
  AspectRatio -> 3/4, PlotStyle -> Red], ListPlot[pts]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This approach also works with

```
SeedRandom[0];
pts = RandomSample@Table[{Cos[3.2 t], Sin[2 t]}, {t, 0., 3.2, 0.02}];
```

`FindCurvePath` splits `pts` into four connecting segments.

**V8 - V10.1 Solution**

This works in V10.1 and V9.0.1 (presumably in V8) in place of `FindHamiltonPath`:

```
g = Graph@ edges;
path = FindShortestPath[g, ##] & @@ Flatten[Position[VertexDegree[g], 1]];
```

Comment: I got the error because I was not working on the same data `pts`. Indeed, it works for the `pts` of the OP. I am trying to adapt belisarius's answer to increase robustness. I've deleted my comments above as there are no longer relevant.

Comment: @anderstood Deleted mine likewise.

Comment: Sorting points from one end to the other end seems to make your procedure more robust (see edit in question). I'll see in practise if it's "robust enough" and let you know.

Comment: A case when this method fails: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158320/280