# Is there a way to draw implicit polar equations?

Tags: plotting

I need to plot the polar equation $r^2=\cos\theta$, but I could not find any built-in command in Mathematica to do so. Is there any (simple) way to plot an implicit polar equation?

Answer (score 2):

You can use *Mathematica* to figure out what the corresponding relationship is in cartesian coordinates,

```
r^2 == Cos[th] /. {r -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], th -> ArcTan[x, y]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using `ContourPlot` to plot this:

```
ContourPlot[
 x^2 + y^2 == x/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2],
 {x, 0, 1}, {y, -1, 1}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks. I like to have $x$ and $y$-axis in the graph, and I wonder if it is possible using ContourPlot. But there is also a question, that this graph does not seem include the case $r<0$.

Comment: @James $r$ is always zero or larger in a polar coordinate system... If you have something else in mind, you have to specify what that is. In your coordinate system, how is $r$ related to $x$ and $y$? The options for `ContourPlot` are well documented. Read about `Frame` (which you'll want to set to `False`) and `Axes`.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
PolarPlot[Sqrt[Cos[th]], {th, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Well, the question is "Is there any way to draw the graph of implicit polar equations?" `PolarPlot` works when the relationship is explicit, but not when it is implicit. However, it can be used for the given example, so still worth to mention.

Comment: @C.E. It could be smth like `PolarPlot[Evaluate[r /. Solve[r^2 == Cos[th], r]], {th, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]`

Comment: @garej I was thinking about implicit relationships in polar coordinates where a corresponding explicit formula is hard or impossible to find. Take f.e. `Solve[r^2 == Cos[r th], r]`, this cannot be solved with `Solve`, and hence cannot be plotted with `PolarPlot`. But it can be plotted with `ContourPlot`.

Comment: But this graph does not include when $r$ is negative.

Comment: true, technically is should be `PolarPlot[{-Sqrt[Cos[th]], Sqrt[Cos[th]]}, {th, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]`

Comment: more about these shapes here [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66538/how-do-i-draw-a-pair-of-buttocks)